# How to change the location of a .chm file at runtime

Tags: vb6, chm

I have a .CHM Help file for my VB6 App. I need to change the location, at run time from the help file location specified in the project properties. I DO NOT want to use some form of HTML help. I just need to know how to change the location that the program looks to find the .CHM help file.

Anybody run into this issue?

I want to store the help file on the Server with the data files, not on individual machines running the application.

Comment: Set in the app object.

Answer (score 3):

Set the HelpFile attribute of the App object as below:

```
App.HelpFile = g_Path_to_Your_CHM & "\YourHelpFile.chm"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note there are some security problems with CHM on a Server!

In addition to rags answer above you may want to call the help file like this:

```
Public Sub ShowContents(ByVal intHelpFile As Integer)
HtmlHelp hwnd, HFile(intHelpFile), HH_DISPLAY_TOC, 0
End Sub
```

It's called by :

```
Public Function HFile(ByVal i_HFile As Integer) As String 
'----- Set the string variable to include the application path of helpfile
Select Case i_HFile
Case 1
HFile = App.Path & "\help\CHM-example.chm"
Case 2
'----- Place other Help file paths in successive case statements
HFile = App.Path & "\help\CHM-other-language.chm"
End Select
End Function
```

All this is added by a module:

```
'******************************************************************************
'----- Modul - definition for HTMLHelp - (c) Ulrich Kulle, www.help-info.de
'----- 2002-08-26 Version 1.0 first release
'----- 2005-07-17 Version 1.1 updated for Pop-Up help
'******************************************************************************
'----- Portions of this code courtesy of David Liske.
'----- Thanks to David Liske, Don Lammers, Matthew Brown and Thomas Schulz
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Type HH_IDPAIR
  dwControlId As Long
  dwTopicId As Long
End Type

'This array should contain the number of controls that have
'context-sensitive help, plus one more for a zero-terminating
'pair.

Public ids(2) As HH_IDPAIR

Declare Function GetDlgCtrlID Lib "user32" _
  (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Public Declare Function HtmlHelp Lib "hhctrl.ocx" Alias "HtmlHelpA" _
               (ByVal hwndCaller As Long, ByVal pszFile As String, _
                ByVal uCommand As Long, ByVal dwData As Long) As Long

Declare Function HTMLHelpTopic Lib "hhctrl.ocx" Alias "HtmlHelpA" _
               (ByVal hwndCaller As Long, ByVal pszFile As String, _
                ByVal uCommand As Long, ByVal dwData As String) As Long

Private Declare Function HtmlHelpSearch Lib "hhctrl.ocx" Alias "HtmlHelpA" _
               (ByVal hwndCaller As Long, ByVal pszFile As String, _
                ByVal uCommand As Long, dwData As HH_FTS_QUERY) As Long


Public Const HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC = &H0         ' select last opened tab, [display a specified topic]
Public Const HH_DISPLAY_TOC = &H1           ' select contents tab, [display a specified topic]
Public Const HH_DISPLAY_INDEX = &H2         ' select index tab and searches for a keyword
Public Const HH_DISPLAY_SEARCH = &H3        ' select search tab and perform a search

Private Const HH_SET_WIN_TYPE = &H4
Private Const HH_GET_WIN_TYPE = &H5
Private Const HH_GET_WIN_HANDLE = &H6
Private Const HH_DISPLAY_TEXT_POPUP = &HE   ' Display string resource ID or

Public Const HH_HELP_CONTEXT = &HF          ' display mapped numeric value in dwData

Private Const HH_TP_HELP_CONTEXTMENU = &H10 ' Text pop-up help, similar to WinHelp's HELP_CONTEXTMENU.
Private Const HH_TP_HELP_WM_HELP = &H11     ' text pop-up help, similar to WinHelp's HELP_WM_HELP.


Public Type HH_FTS_QUERY                ' UDT for accessing the Search tab
  cbStruct          As Long             ' Sizeof structure in bytes.
  fUniCodeStrings   As Long             ' TRUE if all strings are unicode.
  pszSearchQuery    As String           ' String containing the search query.
  iProximity        As Long             ' Word proximity.
  fStemmedSearch    As Long             ' TRUE for StemmedSearch only.
  fTitleOnly        As Long             ' TRUE for Title search only.
  fExecute          As Long             ' TRUE to initiate the search.
  pszWindow         As String           ' Window to display in
End Type

Public Function HFile(ByVal i_HFile As Integer) As String
'----- Set the string variable to include the application path of helpfile
  Select Case i_HFile
  Case 1
    HFile = App.Path & "\help\CHM-example.chm"
  Case 2
'----- Place other Help file paths in successive case statements
    HFile = App.Path & "\help\CHM-other-language.chm"
  End Select
End Function

Public Sub ShowContents(ByVal intHelpFile As Integer)
   HtmlHelp hwnd, HFile(intHelpFile), HH_DISPLAY_TOC, 0
End Sub

Public Sub ShowIndex(ByVal intHelpFile As Integer)
    HtmlHelp hwnd, HFile(intHelpFile), HH_DISPLAY_INDEX, 0
End Sub

Public Sub ShowTopic(ByVal intHelpFile As Integer, strTopic As String)
    HTMLHelpTopic hwnd, HFile(intHelpFile), HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC, strTopic
End Sub

Public Sub ShowTopicID(ByVal intHelpFile As Integer, IdTopic As Long)
  HtmlHelp hwnd, HFile(intHelpFile), HH_HELP_CONTEXT, IdTopic
End Sub
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'----- display the search tab
'----- bug: start searching with a string dosn't work
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Sub ShowSearch(ByVal intHelpFile As Integer)
Dim searchIt As HH_FTS_QUERY
  With searchIt
    .cbStruct = Len(searchIt)
    .fUniCodeStrings = 1&
    .pszSearchQuery = "foobar"
    .iProximity = 0&
    .fStemmedSearch = 0&
    .fTitleOnly = 1&
    .fExecute = 1&
    .pszWindow = ""
  End With
  Call HtmlHelpSearch(0&, HFile(intHelpFile), HH_DISPLAY_SEARCH, searchIt)
End Sub
```